# Reorder geojson points

Tags: geojson, turfjs

Is there a way to reorder points in geojson so that my line "sticks" to the road.  Right now I tried sorting based on longitude, but "S" shaped curves puts some points out of gps sequence, but in sort order (hence, the zig-zag)

[image]

How would I go about reordering my points correctly?  Currently I'm using [turf](http://turfjs.org/) for other stuff, but another library would also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Where did these points come from? If they were ordered either chronologically or antichronologically, then perhaps that order was fine to begin with. Perhaps there is additional metadata that can help order your points with ease.

If not, the only thing I can think of is to employ some sort of nearest neighbor sorting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_chain_algorithm

This page: https://github.com/pastelsky/nnc seems to be the source of the animation seen on wikipedia and relies on javascript code, so perhaps you can make use of the underyling library used?